# Contructing a special tree, from numerical sequence

Tags: graph, binary-tree, theory

I have an interesting task, but I have no clue how to solve it.

The minim binary tree M(a) for a given sequence a= (a1, . . . , an) without repeated elements is defined as follows: Be ai the minimal number of (a1, . . . , an), and then the root of M(a) is ai, its left subtree is M(a1, . . . , ai-1) and its right subtree is M(ai+1, . . . . , an). M(∅) is a empty tree. For a given sequence, construct a minimum tree in O(n). Notice that subtrees are also M so they have to follow the rules.

[image: Example]
Example here.
Thx for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called cartesian tree. Article about creating one here: https://iq.opengenus.org/cartesian-tree/

Comment: You can see the implementation here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cartesian-tree/

Comment: @risingStark yes but on geeksforgeeks they dont have O(n), its O(N^2)

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Users\James\code\minbin>minbin
1 -> 2
2 -> 3
3 -> 7
3 -> 5
5 -> 11
5 -> 8
8 -> 15
8 -> 19
1 -> 12
12 -> 13
```

You can see the code that produces this output at https://gist.github.com/JamesBremner/ac9ad8db15eafaad57a89532e64ff7bf

The algorithm is recursive:

- find smallest element
- link parent to smallest
- split remaining numbers
- if left is single, link from smallest, else call split again
- if right is single, link from smallest, else call split again
- return